# How can I get current location data?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am interested in obtaining current user location in application created with android studio (and google maps api). There is this link which may be considered a guidance: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#java 
however with code related to following:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if(location != null) {
                        LatLng lastLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLocation));
                    }
                    else{
                        LatLng fixedLocation = new LatLng(52.237049, 21.017532);
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(fixedLocation));
                    }
                }
            });
```

It doesn't seem that camera is moved to my actual place or the one that is hard coded.
How can I obtain current location data?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the camera animating & zooming to particular location, then you should use -

```
LatLng lastLocation = new LatLng(52.237049, 21.017532);
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(lastLocation, 16)); // 16 - zoom level.
```

Comment: I'm interested in getting location data.
I can move camera to fixed location outside of onSuccess but I'm not sure what exactly is not working as instructions related to if and else don't (if I'm not mistaken) trigger.

Comment: You should first try this code on mapReady(). Comment if & else and see your condition is met.